# Golarion deity closest to Dionysus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, religions-and-deities, golarion

I have a character concept for a Cleric with a focus on alcohol, celebration, madness, and fertility. In Greek mythology, Dionysus would be a perfect fit.

In Golarion, I think my best bet may be [Cayden Cailean](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Cayden_Cailean) who's associated with joy, revelry, booze, and liberation...but lacks the darker side of Dionysus, or the association with madness or fertility.

Are there other Golarion options worth considering? Any Paizo material is fine, and 3rd party is likely fine too, if it's meant for use in Golarion. I'm happy to choose a more obscure demigod / first world / empyrial lord and happy to consider a deity from anywhere on Golarion. I'm *not* interested in the "worships a concept" route.

Comment: Bear in mind that any 3PP material meant for use in Golarion can't actually say so, due to it being wholly owned by Paizo and not available for use under the OGL or Pathfinder Compatibility License.  The best it can do is hint strongly that it can be used in something that resembles a Golarion-like setting.  I would guess that any "generic" 3PP material not intended for a specific setting ought to work just fine, but I'm not sure if this would be specific enough for your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sun Wukong](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Sun_Wukong), the Monkey King, is CN; all the 9 gods with Revelry as a domain are CG in a startling lack of originality (Cayden, Cernunnos, Desna, Hembad, Keltheald, Kofusachi, Marishi, Reymenda, Thisamet).

If he looks too cuddly, you should see Stephen Chow's latest movie [Journey to the West: Conquering the Demons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West%3a_Conquering_the_Demons) where he's the bad guy.

But I'd instead be tempted to put a bit of a Dionysian shine on Caylean, which would make him a lot more interesting.  Happy drunken swashbuckler or violent drunken frat boy date rapist? It's a fine line. In D&D worlds sometimes people get obsessed with one god having to be depicted uniformly; that's not the way it works in the real world and luckily not in Golarion either; Sarenrae is a good example of a goddess whose worshippers take a strong divide along nicey-nice and heretic-killing lines.

Comment: Yup, just looking at the various denominations based around the Christian God in our own world you can see the scope for some variety in Caylean's churches.  Just have an offshoot chapter that sees things a bit differently.

Comment: Just to add to the alternate take idea: There's a reason that clerics generally just need to be within one step of their deity.  A CN worshipper of Caylean could certainly embrace "darker" fun than most worshippers do.